# How to skip the first few entries in a "load more" scenario with Element API?

Tags: craft3, php, plugin-elementapi, javascript

I have a website that uses a "load more" button. The process for this button can be found here:

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/infinite-scrolling-and-lazy-loading-with-craft-cms

I made it pretty much verbatim (structure-wise with Element API) to that article, but I want to skip the first 6 entries because they are featured elsewhere on the site. So I tried to add `.offset('6')` to the for loop, and that did skip the first 6 entries. But when the "load more" button is clicked it would display the second 6 entries again (duplicates) then when you click the button again it properly continues down the list of entries.

So, how can I skip the first 6 entries in this scenario without having duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always want to skip the first 6 entries, you can modify the Element API endpoint to add 6 to the offset number in the query criteria:

```
$criteria = [
    'section' => $settings['section'], 
    'limit' =>  $settings['limit'],
    'offset' =>  ($settings['limit'] * Craft::$app->request->getParam('offset')) + 6,
    'order' => $settings['orderBy'],
];
```

That should mean you're always receiving results that are offset by the required amount for your request, *plus* the first 6 entries that you always want to skip.

Comment: That worked! How would I do it if I only wanted to skip the first 6 just on the homepage and not elsewhere?

Comment: I thought this might deserve its own question, so I opened a new question here: (https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35754/how-to-use-multiple-different-instances-element-api-load-more-button)